# passing information from <input type="file" id="theFile"/> though another buttons onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am so very new to MVC and web development. I need to pass a token which i already have, then the filename and file which I'm trying to get off a `<input type="file" id="theFile"/>` and then also need the date. Once i can get this info into the Home controller i can use C# and then i know whats going on. But at the moment I'm not sure if I'm even on the right path.

How would i pass these values though to the controller with the button??

In my View:

```
<input type="file" id="theFile"/>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="Upload(token = Model.Token, fileName = theFile.Value.tostring(), modDate = date.now, file = theFile.value);" >Upload file to the website</button>
```

In the HomeControler:

```
 public ActionResult Upload(string token, string filename, string moddate, object file)
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't call your controller's action methods directly from the HTML. If you're uploading data, the standard way to do this would be to post a form to the server.

So you've got a file input in your view, looks like you may need a hidden field containing the token, or get this from a cookie, it depends on your implementation.

You'll want to make sure you have a `<form>` in your view; in MVC you'd do something like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("yourControllerName", "Upload"))
{
   all your form elements here
}
```

And finally add an `[HttpPost]` attribute to your `Upload` action method. MVC will take care of mapping your form elements to `Upload`'s parameters.

Comment: Where you say all you form elements here, is that where my tags go or my variables? im unsure?

Comment: @Pommy I mean your tags, so stuff like `<input type="file" id="theFile"/>`

Comment: Thanks, so <input type="file" id="theFile"/> should go in the <Form> and the other button i should change to a submit? and keep it out side the form or keep it inside?

Comment: @Pommy yes, it's just a standard HTML form - all form elements (input, textarea, etc) inside the `<form>` will be posted. You also need the submit button inside the form, so the browser knows which form to submit.

Comment: Thanks :), so from the controller how would i get the file and file name after the submit button is pushed?

Comment: Scott Hanselman has a great, detailed description of the whole process: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx